# How to compare Uri and file android

Tags: android

I am launching a file picker intent. And I am getting a URI of the file from data.getData() method on onActivityResult . There I have a utility class for getting the real path of files from the URI. I want to check whether the path returned from the utility class is valid or not by comparing it with URI. **Let assume the utility class returned the path of a different file by mistake. I don't want to use the file name to compare. is there any way?**

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==IMAGE_FILE_PICKER_CODE&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        String path = null;
        try {
            path = new PathUtils(getActivity()).getPath(data.getData()); //Utility class to get path from uri

            File file = new File(path); //want to compare this file with data.getData()
```

Comment: It starts with that you should not even try to get a file system path for a nice uri. Use the uri for all. Trying to get a path worked often  on Android below 10 but was never a good idea as the uri could be used directly.

Comment: URI cant be used for all use cases..some times we need the path of the file to perform various operation.

Comment: Yes keep it vague. This will help.  And i never need a path anymore.